# How to fix flaw with context steering

Tags: ai, steering-behaviors

I have implemented steering behaviours where I get eight cardinal directions and calculate the 'interest' and 'danger' values for each direction and get the average of these for the enemy's output direction. It works very well for the most part but in certain situations it fails. Like for example in the image below, there is an obstacle between the player (bottom) and the enemy (top) and so the best calculated directions will be SW and SE because S is blocked, thus the enemy will calculate the best direction as the average of the two which of course would equal the blocked path south..

[image]
[image]

This can be solved in many cases with breadcrumbs since usually the player will be in sight of the enemy if he is in pursuit and thus when moving behind the obstacle a breadcrumb would be placed in the last position in sight. But in certain cases the enemy would be alert whilst the player is out of sight (maybe he heard the player or was signalled alert by another enemy), in which case he would be unable to navigate around the obstacle.

Any thoughts on methods to solve this issue?

Comment: I think averaging all vectors is the wrong solution here. Have you considered taking the longest vector, and using a weighted average between it and its immediate neighbours? That still allows smooth transitions from one semi-cardinal direction to another, without the problem of two large vectors separated by a gap averaging to an unrepresentative value pointing to the valley in between the peaks.

Comment: @DMGregory Yes I tried that previously but it worked better in most situations to take the average of all eight directions. The average of all directions was what was originally proposed by Andrew Fray who came up with the method. But in this case the top would be SW and its immediate neighbours W and S so  it would probably take him around the obstacle based on those values. I'll do some tests with it.

Comment: @DMGregory I did some tests and he actually can't get past the obstacle with the neighbour method. He starts to head SW around the obstacle as predicted but then changes his mind and tries to go SE instead and can't make his mind up darting left and right until crashing into the obstacle.

Comment: @DMGregory The problem is that the enemy is ever so slightly to the east so he should probably go south east around the obstacle, _but_ the player is ever so slightly to the west so he's getting better interest values for the west and thus tries to go SW,.But when he gets nearer he gets more danger signals from the obstacle and tries to go SE but by then he's not in a good position. It's really 50/50 which way to go around the obstacle. A human would just make a decision but the AI here won't as it is.